# Assigning common key value across related events in time series

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Healthcare scenario, imagine a journal table of patient events (admission, transfers, discharges).  What we want to do is parse the stream into blocks bounded by patient discharges.

```
CREATE TABLE #History
(
    PatientID INT, 
    EventID INT, 
    EventType VARCHAR(20), 
    BeginDate DATE, 
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #History
VALUES
(1,1,'Admission','1/1/2022','1/4/2022'),
(1,2,'Transfer','1/5/2022','1/9/2022'),
(1,3,'Discharge','1/10/2022','1/10/2022'),
(2,4,'Transfer','3/6/22','4/11/22'),
(2,5,'Transfer','4/12/22','4/14/22'),
(2,6,'Transfer','4/15/22','4/19/22'),
(2,7,'Discharge','4/20/22','4/20/22'),
(2,8,'Return','3/6/23','4/11/23'),
(2,9,'Transfer','4/12/23','9/19/23'),
(2,10,'Discharge','9/20/23','9/20/23'),
(3,11,'Admission','2/6/22',NULL),
(4,12,'Admission','3/4/23',NULL)
--millions more
```

What I'm looking for is a result set that returns the initial event in a sequence that tags each record with (1) the first event since the last discharge or (2) the first event if no discharge.  Events sequences may or may not begin with an admission but they always end with a discharge.  The same patient may present multiple times (see PatientID 2).  Results to look like this:

| PatientID | EventID | InitialEventID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 | 8 |
| 2 | 10 | 8 |
| 3 | 11 | 11 |
| 4 | 12 | 12 |

This is a very large dataset and need a set-based operation. I've tinkered with RANK() and LAG functions, self joins, etc. but just haven't been able to crack it.  Thank you

Comment: --millions more. If that is the case, you may want to put an index on the #table after you load it, so it does not become a heap. This will improve performance if used in any other way than a pure dump.

Comment: Search for islands and gaps. This is going to very likely be a performance problem because the logic here is pretty rough. Would be a much better database design if you had an Admissions or Events table that would let you assign a value to all these rows until the patient is discharged.

Comment: Super helpful @SeanLange, you've given me a classic problem domain to start with.  Unfortunately I'm at the mercy of my EMR vendor (I don't control the ODS) and this task is to try to ETL this data into something we can use by an analyst without a pHD in SQL-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query produces the results

```
;WITH MarkersS AS ( -- find every discharge or patientes without last event for patients without discharge
    SELECT PatientID, EventId
    FROM #History 
    WHERE EventType = 'Discharge'
    UNION ALL     
    SELECT PatientID, MAX (EventID) EventId
    FROM #History h
    WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #History h1
        WHERE h.PatientID = h1.PatientID
            AND h1.EventType = 'Discharge'
        )
    GROUP BY h.PatientID
), Markers AS (
SELECT *, LAG(MarkersS.EventID, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY MarkersS.PatientID ORDER BY MarkersS.EventID) Prev
FROM MarkersS
)
SELECT h.PatientID, h.EventID, MIN(h.EventID) OVER (PARTITION BY Markers.EventID) InitialEventID
FROM Markers
INNER JOIN #History h
    ON h.PatientID = Markers.PatientID
        AND h.EventID > Markers.Prev 
        AND h.EventID <= Markers.EventID
```

But as @Ross Bush indicates requires index

I might be better to split the approach, introduce a working table and create some columnstore index columnstore index as well. Since I don't have lot quantity of data it's really hard to figure out what the index would be. Same process but with working table would looks like

```
;WITH MarkersS AS ( -- find every discharge or patientes without last event for patients without discharge
    SELECT PatientID, EventId, CAST( NULL as INT) Prev
    FROM #History 
    WHERE EventType = 'Discharge'
    UNION ALL     
    SELECT PatientID, MAX (EventID) EventId, 0 as Prev
    FROM #History h
    WHERE NOT EXISTS  (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #History h1
        WHERE h.PatientID = h1.PatientID
            AND h1.EventType = 'Discharge'
        )
    GROUP BY h.PatientID
)
SELECT *
INTO #Markers
FROM MarkersS
;with Markers AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(MarkersS.EventID, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY MarkersS.PatientID ORDER BY MarkersS.EventID) PrevC
    FROM #Markers MarkersS
    WHERE Prev IS NULL
)
-- 
UPDATE Markers 
set Prev = PrevC
-- bring results 
SELECT h.PatientID, h.EventID, MIN(h.EventID) OVER (PARTITION BY Markers.EventID) InitialEventID
FROM #Markers Markers
INNER JOIN #History h
    ON h.PatientID = Markers.PatientID
        AND h.EventID > Markers.Prev and h.EventID <= Markers.EventID
```

Comment: Thanks- Small problem with the nested query- the WHERE NOT EXISTS was trimming records that have a preceding discharge for any patient sequences that didn't END in discharge (I reworked it a little). This gave me a huge, HUGE head start though.  It even performs well, which is good because the source ODS is vendor hosted and I can't index-